# How to prevent "mouse move" event when Cursor is set to locked using Unity new input system?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am adding controller and KBM support to a game. I would like for this to work as follows:

If user presses any button on the controller, the UI responds by showing controller related input icons and hiding the mouse cursor.

If user moves the mouse or presses a key, the UI responds by showing KBM related input icons and displaying the mouse cursor.

My solution for this is to simply call a method that appropriately informs the UI of the most recent device used and hides or shows the mouse based on that. This method gets called on every input, but it doesn't really do anything if the input didn't change from the last call.

The problem I am having is on hiding the mouse. To respond to mouse movement I setup a listener for it as such:

```
protected void OnEnable()
{
    GameInput.UI.Point.performed += OnMouseMove;
    GameInput.UI.Point.Enable();
}

private void OnMouseMove() 
{
    //inform UI of change to KBM
    UnityEngine.Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None; //unlock cursor
    UnityEngine.Cursor.visible = true; //show cursor
}
```

Whenever the input device changes to the gamepad, the following code is ran:

```
private void OnInputDeviceChangedToGamePad() 
{
    //inform UI of change to GamePad
    UnityEngine.Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked; //here is where my problem begins
}
```

When the lockstate is set to locked Unity oddly fires GameInput.UI.Point.performed. This causes the OnMouseMove method to run, which sets the current input device to KBM and unlocks the cursor.

I have tried a few different approaches to fix this:

- Rearranging the order of the code in hopes that while the mouse event fires, the change to gamepad occurs after. This doesn't work because once the cursor is locked, mouse is fired and unhidden.
- Using coroutines along with a bool to delay timing and only unlock cursor if the bool is set properly.

The second one works, but it isn't consistent, and other code changes have rendered it quite unreliable. Also, it's a bit of hack that messes things up because the setting of the input device is delayed, and so code can run that might depend on having it set properly.

I'm at a loss here. How can I set the lockstate of the cursor without calling the .performed phase of the InputAction? Is there another approach to this that perhaps I'm missing?

Comment: why does the `lockState` need to be set to `Locked` when in Gamepad mode? Is it not enough to just hide the Cursor?

Comment: Unsubscribe from the events?

Comment: @SlackGroverglow if the cursor is just made invisible, then anything with IPointerEnter/IPointerExit will still fire if the mouse is moved. If gamepad is activated while cursor is actively hovering something, it will remain hovering. Locking it forces IPointerExit to fire.

Comment: @BugFinder I'm not sure what events you're referring to.

Comment: the input events that you didnt want running - hence the title of your question

Comment: @BugFinder So, when device is changed to gamepad, unsubscribe from mousemove event, lock the mouse (which moves it), then resubscribe? I'm not certain this is what you meant, but this may actually work. I will test and come back with answer, or ask you to post as answer.

Comment: Its actually exactly how i meant. Unsub when you dont need. Sub when you do

Comment: @BugFinder Your suggestion has led me to a solution, albeit with a slight modification needed. Do you want to post an answer, or should I just post my final solution?

Comment: I am less desperate for points :) feel free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @BugFinder, the solution to this problem is to simply unregister the Mouse's performed action from OnMouseMove prior to locking the mouse, and then re-register afterwards. Additionally, a good approach would be to leave the event unregistered while in KBM mode.

However, there is on slight issue with this: locking the mouse does not complete its movement instantly, it does so within the current frame. Thus, you would need to at least use `yield return null;` before registering again. I opted to add a small time delay instead of just the frame, to prevent the user from rapidly switching back and forth between KBM and gamepad.

My solution looks like this:

```
private void OnInputDeviceChangedToGamePad() 
{
    GameInput.UI.Point.performed -= OnMouseMove;
    //inform UI of change to GamePad
    UnityEngine.Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    StartCoroutine(DelayMouseMoveRegistration());
}

private IEnumerator DelayMouseMoveRegistration() 
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.5f);
    GameInput.UI.Point.performed += OnMouseMove;
}
```